# Why does my django template not recognize the url parameters I set in my views.py file?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I am building an event management app using Django. I have created a dynamic calendar, and I'm trying to add a link to next months calendar in my navigation.

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name = 'home'),
    path('<int:year>/<str:month>/', views.home),
]
```

In my views.py file I added parameters like so:

```
def home(request, year=datetime.now().year, month=datetime.now().strftime('%B')):
```

```
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'home' '2021' 'November' %}">November</a>
</li>
```

When I add the two arguments, I get a template rendering error:

> Reverse for 'home' with arguments '('2021', 'November')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['$']

When I remove the two arguments and only leave 'home' the template error goes away, and I'm not sure why. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you show the contents of your urls file so we can see how your mapping the url to the method?

Comment: Please ensure all relevant information is provided to users to help you answer your question.

Comment: Just added my urls.py file!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have here are two different urls which happen to be handled by the same view.  The first url is your home page with no date specified, and the second is your page with a year and month specified.

Handle these as two differently named url patterns, eg:

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('<int:year>/<str:month>/', views.home, name='byyearmonth'),
]
```

Template:

```
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'byyearmonth' '2021' 'November' %}">November</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your [URLconf](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/) doesn't specify your two arguments (correctly). It should probably look something like this:

```py
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('/<int:year>/<str:month>/', views.home, name='home'),
]
```

Comment: very delayed, but thank you for your help, I just went back to this project and now it makes perfect sense.